# how to get sever side var value?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

in aspx code behind, define a var like:

```
Public rate as decimal;
```

then in page markup, put a control like:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="myRate" runat="server" Value='<%=rate%>'/>
```

then in javascript try to test this value:

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%=myRate.ClientID%>').value);
```

it gave me the value as <%=myRate%>, not something like 0.01 in alert popup.

How to resolve this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Server tags aren't evaluated in this case (which is why you see the literal text):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="myRate" runat="server" Value='<%=rate%>'/>
```

The easiest options are to set it in the code-behind:

```
myRate.Value = rate;
```

or, unless it needs to be a server control, just use a hidden input:

```
<input id="myRate" type="hidden" value="<%=rate%>" />
```

And get it using that ID:

```
document.getElementById('myRate').value
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting the value in the page load in the code behind,

I am suprised this approach  worked as I didnt think you could use the response.write construct in a server control?

Another option may be to set it via the binding syntax so

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="myRate" runat="server" Value='<%#this.rate%>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

How I would do it

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="MyRate" runat="server" Value="<%# this.rate %>" />
```

Then in my javascript:

```
alert(document.getElementById('<%=myRate.ClientID%>').value);
```